# Getting image url in Angular from API

Tags: angular

I am following this [link](https://medium.com/techinpieces/blobs-with-http-post-and-angular-5-a-short-story-993084811af4)
to show user image in UI in Angular 10.

I am doing this for POST call

```
return this.http.post<any>(url, taxProProfileServiceInput, { responseType: 'blob' as 'json' })
  .pipe(tap(response => {
    return response;
  }, err => this.handleError(err)));
```

The problem is i get the response as

> data:text/plain;base64,aHR0cHM

In HTML:

```
    <img [src]="imageToShow"
 alt="Place image title" />
```

But since the converted type is data:text/plain, image src is not working.
I tried replacing text:plain to image/png and image/jpeg but nothing working.
I read many posts and articles but every where i get the response as data:text/plain.

Comment: `aHR0cHM` decoded is just `https` is that the image data you are getting?

Comment: data:text/plain;base64,aHR0cHM, has more characters i have trimmed it down just for this post..  the problem is image [src] will not understand text/plain. And when i go to data:text/plain;base64,aHR0cHM in browser url: i gives me jpg image link.